# Sort a small number of items

Tags: cobol

I'm trying to do a program to take 3 numbers into variables and output them in ascending order.

I mean this (example):

```
accept num1
accept num2 
accept num3
```

and then sort it.

Comment: We might help a lot if you show your code and describe the problem you're having. (Also, is there a reason you tagged with both `ibm-midrange` and `cobol85`? They don't seem well connected.)

Comment: I don't have the code, I'm planning the idea yet.

It's simple ( i guess) someone introduce 3 numbers ( as 3 7 and 4) and the program sort that numbers by ascending ( result : 3 4 7 ) 

the question is how can i do that, has COBOL got functions for that or something?

Answer (score 1):

For a very limited number of items, a simple "exchange sort" will be fine. Use a table with OCCURS, put the data in the table, and then keep passing the table, swapping adjacent items, until in a pass of the table there are no more changes.

For three numbers, you may want to consider something like this, which isn't actually a sort, but will give you the order that you want.

```
   DATA DIVISION. 
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION. 
   01  NUM1 PIC 9. 
   01  NUM2 PIC 9. 
   01  NUM3 PIC 9. 
   01  SNUM1 PIC 9. 
   01  SNUM2 PIC 9. 
   01  SNUM3 PIC 9. 
   PROCEDURE DIVISION. 
       ACCEPT                       NUM1 
       ACCEPT                       NUM2 
       ACCEPT                       NUM3 
       COMPUTE SNUM1 =              FUNCTION
                                     MIN 
                                      ( 
                                      NUM1 
                                      NUM2 
                                      NUM3 
                                      ) 
       COMPUTE SNUM2 =              FUNCTION
                                     MEDIAN 
                                      ( 
                                      NUM1 
                                      NUM2 
                                      NUM3 
                                      ) 
       COMPUTE SNUM3 =              FUNCTION
                                     MAX 
                                      ( 
                                      NUM1 
                                      NUM2 
                                      NUM3 
                                      ) 
       DISPLAY 
               ">" 
               SNUM1 
               "<" 
       DISPLAY 
               ">" 
               SNUM2
               "<" 
       DISPLAY 
               ">" 
               SNUM3
               "<" 
       GOBACK 
       .
```

With this on SYSIN (or wherever you ACCEPT from):

```
4
2
3
```

It will produce:

```
>2<
>3<
>4<
```

Personally I'd go for something like this:

```
   DATA DIVISION. 
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION. 
   01  NUM1 PIC 9. 
   01  NUM2 PIC 9. 
   01  NUM3 PIC 9. 
   01  SNUM1 PIC 9. 
   01  SNUM2 PIC 9. 
   01  SNUM3 PIC 9. 
   PROCEDURE DIVISION. 
       ACCEPT                       NUM1 
       ACCEPT                       NUM2 
       ACCEPT                       NUM3 
       IF ( NUM2 
         LESS THAN NUM1 ) 
           MOVE NUM2                TO SNUM1
           MOVE NUM1                TO SNUM2
       ELSE 
           MOVE NUM2                TO SNUM1
           MOVE NUM1                TO SNUM2
       END-IF 
       EVALUATE TRUE 
         WHEN NUM3 
               LESS THAN SNUM1 
             MOVE SNUM2             TO SNUM3
             MOVE SNUM1             TO SNUM2
             MOVE NUM3              TO SNUM1
         WHEN NUM3 
               LESS THAN SNUM2 
             MOVE SNUM2             TO SNUM3
             MOVE NUM3              TO SNUM2
         WHEN OTHER 
             MOVE NUM3              TO SNUM3
       END-EVALUATE 
       DISPLAY 
               ">" 
               SNUM1 
               "<" 
       DISPLAY 
               ">" 
               SNUM2
               "<" 
       DISPLAY 
               ">" 
               SNUM3
               "<" 
       GOBACK 
       .
```

Decides the order of the first two numbers, then works out where the third should go. This is effectively a combined exchange/insertion sort :-)

Same results as the above, of course.

COBOL does have a SORT verb, if that is what you are supposed to be using, but it is "overkill" for three items.